# The metric flink.task.isBackPressured will not be reported because only number types are supported by this reporter

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When the Flink cluster is running, the INFO log was output time from time:

> org.apache.flink.metrics.datadog.DatadogHttpReporter         [] - The metric flink.task.isBackPressured will not be reported because only number types are supported by this reporter.

Does anyone know what is the problem with this metrics?

I am using the Datadog for the metric reporter and I need to know which Flink tasks were back pressured.

Comment: What flink and metrics reporter version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`isBackPressured` is a boolean, and has the limitation you've run into when used with the datadog reporter.

Fortunately there's a better way to assess backpressure that's available since Flink 1.13: you can look at `backPressuredTimeMsPerSecond` and related metrics. These metrics are based on a smoothed aggregation measured over a couple of seconds, and thus provide a more meaningful view of the actual behavior than `isBackPressured`, which is a point-in-time snapshot of whether a task was (perhaps only momentarily) backpressured.

See [the docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/metrics/#io) for more details.